# How can I Change File name in Maxscript?

Tags: 3dsmax, maxscript

I don't know how to specify a name and directory for the render output.

How can I do so in the render function?

I'll be thankful if you give me a snippet of code for video rendering with max script

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small snippet from a script that I use to render unit-testing scenes:

```
local extension = ".png"
local suffix = ""
if rendTimeType != 1 do (
    -- Add suffix to separate frame numbers if not single-frame render
    suffix = "_"
)
rendOutputFilename = outputDir + filename + suffix + extension
rendSaveFile = true
```

Note that `rendTimeType`, `rendOutputFilename` and `rendSaveFile` are 3ds Max variables.  The rest of them are local variables that I've set.  I'm sure you get the idea.

Check the [documentation](http://help.autodesk.com/view/3DSMAX/2021/ENU/?guid=GUID-30AF1E53-5A69-402D-84D6-4D6ECCDD6D20) for more information.